# How to implement gapless playback (API 7+)

Tags: android, media-player

Can anyone recommend a way to implement gapless music playback (eg. loading 2 files and not experiencing a gap between files - API7+)? (I am currently thinking of using an InputStream or something)

Something like this has been asked back in 2012:
[see question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992621/android-gapless-playback-of-a-looped-audio-file-in-mediaplayer)

I saw something a couple of years ago that played files like this:
[link here (about streaming)](http://blog.infidian.com/2009/12/27/android-streaming-mediaplayer-tutorial-updated-to-v1-5-cupcake/)

Thanks for any ideas.